# How do you give specific teams command access in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-commands

How do you give specific teams command access in Minecraft? I'm setting up a rank system on my server, and I want a certain rank to have access to a couple commands, not all though. How might I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Flagging as unclear because the question lacks an edition tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Vanilla Minecraft. You can't even use selectors for `/op`.

The reason for this is that OP should be used sparingly and any automation of this could lead to disastrous results if it goes wrong.

You could install a server mod to do what you asked, but I recommend instead thinking about if you really need it.